# Textbox macro to add or subtract days and select date on calendar (Datepicker)

Tags: vba, excel

Basic setup is, there are 2 textboxes and 1 calendar (Datepicker).

In textbox1, user enter date in either of the format mentioned below, press enter, date
gets **selected** on the calendar.

03-Feb

03-Feb-17

03-Feb-17

In textbox2, user enter days that needs to be added or subtracted as below, press enter,
date gets selected on the calendar.

+1, +15, +32... and so on to add days

-1, -12, -21... and so on to subtract days

Textbox1 code below works fine -

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim txt As String, dayStr As String, monthStr As String, yearStr As String
    Dim okTxt As Boolean

    txt = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Select Case Len(txt)
        Case 2
            dayStr = txt
            okTxt = okDay(dayStr)
            monthStr = Month(Now)
            yearStr = Year(Now)
        Case 5
            dayStr = Mid(txt, 3, 3)
            monthStr = Mid(txt, 3, 3)
            okTxt = okDay(Left(txt, 2)) And okMonth(monthStr)
            yearStr = Year(Now)
        Case 7
            dayStr = Mid(txt, 3, 3)
            monthStr = Mid(txt, 3, 3)
            yearStr = Mid(txt, 6, 2)
            okTxt = okDay(Left(txt, 2)) And okMonth(monthStr) And okYear(yearStr)
    End Select
    If Not okTxt Then
        MsgBox "Invalid date" _
               & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Date must be input in one of the following formats:" _
               & vbCrLf & vbTab & "dd" _
               & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ddmmm" _
               & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ddmmmyy" _
               & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please try again", vbCritical

        Cancel = True
    Else
        Me.Calendar1.Value = CDate(Left(txt, 2) & " " & monthStr & " " & yearStr)
    End If
End Sub

Function okDay(txt As String) As Boolean
    okDay = CInt(txt) > 0 And CInt(txt) < 31
End Function

Function okMonth(txt As String) As Boolean
    Const months As String = "JANFEBMARAPRMAJJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"
    okMonth = InStr(months, UCase(txt)) > 0
End Function

Function okYear(txt As String) As Boolean
    okYear = CInt(txt) > 0 And CInt(txt) < 200 '<--| set your "limit" years
End Function
```

Textbox2 code below is where I need assistance -

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim Ln As Variant
Dim x As Variant
Dim d As Variant
Dim fmt As Variant
If IsNumeric(Left(TextBox1, 2)) Then Ln = 0 Else Ln = 1
x = Left(TextBox2.Value, 1)
If x <> "-" And x <> "+" Then MsgBox "Please use an operator with your value":: Exit Sub
d = TextBox1.Value
Select Case Len(d)
    Case 4, 5
        d = Left(d, 2 - Ln) & "-" & Right(d, 3)
        fmt = "ddmmm"
    Case 6, 7
        d = Left(d, 2 - Ln) & "-" & Mid(d, 3 - Ln, 3) & "-" & Right(d, Len(d) - (5 - Ln))
        fmt = "ddmmmyy"
    Case 8, 9
        d = Left(d, 2 - Ln) & "-" & Mid(d, 3 - Ln, 3) & "-" & Right(d, Len(d) - (5 - Ln))
        fmt = "ddmmmyyyy"
End Select
MsgBox Format(CDate(d) + Val(TextBox2.Value), fmt)
End Sub
```

Currently what is happening is -

User enter days that needs to added or subtracted in textbox2, press enter, a messagebox
appears showing the end result.

Rather than a messagebox, I simply want the code to **select** the end result on the calendar.

I'm not sure how to change textbox2 code to achieve this.

Kindly assist.

Note : Just like textbox1, where the code **selects** the date on calendar, I want textbox2 code to do the same, which is **select** date on calendar after days are added or subtracted.

Comment: `monthStr = Month(Now)` won't return a valid Month abbreviation. You might want to use `Format(Now, "mmm")` instead, but note that is is locale sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substitute:

```
MsgBox Format(CDate(d) + Val(TextBox2.Value), fmt)
```

with:

```
Me.Calendar1.Value = CDate(d) + Val(TextBox2.Value)
```